# React: JSDOM 13 Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've created a test for a custom hook. all test pass but I receive the error and not sure how to find the root cause. I've trying going through this [link](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/293) but I was unable to find any helpful information.
The hook is just has an axios request. there is no part where I'm directly assigning the location.href which is another thing i've seen that's usually the cause for this error

```
import axios from 'axios'

jest.mock('axios')
describe('hooks', ()=>{

  it('test custom hook', async()=>{
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = await renderHook(()=> customHook())
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(dataJSON)
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // received 0
    await waitForNextUpdate()
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) //received 2
  })
})
```

error:

```
console.error node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
        at Object.dispatchError (C:\project\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:60:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (C:\project\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:674:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:203:15)
        at Request.onRequestError (C:\project\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
        at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) undefined
```

jest-config:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|sass)$": "<rootDir>/_mocks_/styleMock.js"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "!src/index.js",
      "!src/i18n.js",
      "!<rootDir>/_mocks_/*",
      "!src/setupProxy.js",
    ]
  }
```

custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const userDetailState = {
  userInfo: '',
  loading: true,
  errorText: '',

}

export const customHook = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(userDetailState)

  const transformData = useCallback(
    (result) => {
      setUserDetails({
        ...userDetails,
        userInfo: result.data,
        loading: false
      })
 
    },
    [userDetails]
  )

  const getUserData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get('/userdetails')
      transformData(result)
    } catch (error) {
      setUserDetails({
        ...userDetails,
        loading: false
      })
    }
  }, [transformData, userDetails])

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData()
  }, [])

  return {
    userDetails
  }
}
```

userProvider:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import { Loading } from 'components'
import UserContext from 'context/UserContext'
import { customHook } from 'hooks/User/customHook'

const UserProvider = () => {
  const { userDetails } = customHook()

  const renderContent = () => {
    if (userDetails.loading) {
      return (
        <div className='loading'>
          <Loading size='large' data-testid='userProfileLoadingId' className='loading-content' />
        </div>
      )
    } else return dashbaordComponent
  }

  const contextValue = {
    userDetail: userDetails.userInfo,
  }

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {renderContent()}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: There are several problems in posted code. Is there manual mock of `axios` in `__mocks__` ? It's unclear how it's possible for it to do real requests if it was mocked. Please, confirm if replacing `axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(dataJSON)` with `axios.get.mockResolvedValue(dataJSON)` removes this error, so it could be narrowed down.

Comment: there is no manual mock for axios...I just used `jest.mock('axios')` which automatically mock the axios module. switching to `axios.get.mockResolvedValue` did not remove the error unfortunately

Comment: I added `expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` and that fails because it's being called twice. If i add that line before the `waitForNextUpdate()` and the axios call inside the test..it gets called 0 times..not sure if this is helpful

Comment: `jest.mock('axios')` can pick manual mock from `__mocks__` that can differ from real ones. If there's none, this is not the case. Then the problem is specific to other tests that do requests. It's unknown if this happened in this suite or others. You'll have to narrow down tests that cause this. Yes, the logic in this hook is wrong and will cause multiple requests.

Comment: how is it wrong? or what about it is wrong? maybe that is the issue? this is the only test that gives this error.... when I try to test the hook

Comment: It don't see how it can. If you didn't use `__mocks__`, `jest.mock('axios')` stubs Axios for the entire file, it has no ability to do real requests and physically cannot cause this error. From what you listed, it's more likely that you misinterpreted test output and the error refers to another test, possibly a component that uses this hook. I stand corrected for 'wrong', there are problems (transformData and getUserData shouldn't have inputs, setUserDetails should receive userDetails from `userDetails => ... `updater function rather than a variable) but they won't cause multiple requests.

Comment: The possibility for `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) //received 2` I see is that there was another call in another test that wasn't waited for and it runs simultaneously. `test custom hook` isn't the only test in this file, is it? I'm not sure about `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // received 0`, it should have already been called at this point, also axios.get.mockResolvedValue is supposedly too late, should be above renderHook.

Comment: the only other test in this file is a snapshot test. The error only shows up when the `waitForNextUpdate()` is called..but without that line, the hook will not be covered

Comment: That it's a snapshot doesn't mean it can't cause this. It can, and there could be other XHR requests besides Axios. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. That the error is shown only with waitForNextUpdate means that otherwise the test exists too soon. It's may be not related to this test. Try to extract this test to separate file and test only it.

Comment: I just added the use of the customHook

Comment: Does UserProvider test run in the same test suite? Your real setup differs too much from what you posted, it's impossible to give an answer based on provided information. Consider checking what MCVE is about. Currently you're the only person who can debug it. You can try to use explicit mock and produce debugging info `global.XMLHttpRequest = null; process.on('unhandledRejection', console.warn); jest.mock('axios', () => ({ get: jest.fn(() => { throw new Error('unexpected') } }))`, this will give information on unexpected calls. It may be good for all tests to do this in setupFilesAfterEnv file